# Why does foreign language text not hyphenate even when using Babel? Typst hyphenates it correctly

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation

Why do I not get the same hyphenation results as Typst when using `babel` in LuaLaTeX? I have tried various methods for fixing the issue, but they dont work.

Both use Letterpaper sized paper, use custom top, bottom, left and right 1.5cm margins, 12pt font size, and are using the STIX Two Text Font.

- LuaLaTeX Code:

```
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
    \setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\usepackage[main=english,spanish,russian]{babel} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vspace{-0.125cm} % This corresponds to the top margin set by geometry
\begin{center}
\parskip=0pt
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\LARGE \@title \par }%
{\large \lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}%
\par }%
\vspace{.25cm} % Adjust this value to control the space between the author and date
{\large \@date }%
\end{center}\par 
\vspace{.25cm} % This corresponds to the bottom margin set by geometry
}
\makeatother 

\setlength\parindent{.25cm} 

% }

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\end{minipage}

\selectlanguage{russian}

Как лучше всего получить то, что ты хочешь? - спросила она. Он посмотрел в землю, зная, что ей не понравится его ответ. Он колебался, зная, что правда только повредит. Как он собирался сказать ей это? лучший способ получить то, что он хотел, это оставить ее. Завтра я возвращаюсь в Колорадо после того, как на выходных провел там фестиваль в Санта-Барбаре. Там я буду строить планы на октябрь и постараюсь договориться, чтобы, если возможно, вернуться сюда на день рождения. Я сообщу вам, как только узнаю график приема врача и планы полетов. Стул стоял в углу, где простоял более 25 лет. Единственная разница заключалась в том, что в нем действительно кто-то сидел. Сколько времени прошло с тех пор, как кто-то это делал? По его мнению, десять лет или больше. И все же нельзя было отрицать присутствие в кресле сейчас.

\end{document}
```

Here is the Typst code,

- Template Code:

```
// The project function defines how your document looks.
// It takes your content and some metadata and formats it.
// Go ahead and customize it to your liking!
#let project(title: "", authors: (), date: none, body) = {
  // Set the document's basic properties.
  set document(author: authors, title: title)
  set page(
    paper: "us-letter",
    margin: (left: 15mm, right: 15mm, top: 15mm, bottom: 15mm),
    numbering: "1",
    number-align: center,
  )
  set text(font: "STIX Two Text", lang: "en", 12pt)

  // Set paragraph spacing.
  show par: set block(above: 0.75em, below: 0.75em)

  set heading(numbering: "1.1.")
  set par(leading: 0.58em)

  // Title row.
  align(center)[
    #block(text(weight: 700, 1.75em, title))
    #v(0.8em, weak: true)
    #date
  ]

  // Author information.
  pad(
    top: 0.3em,
    bottom: 0.3em,
    x: 2em,
    grid(
      columns: (1fr,) * calc.min(3, authors.len()),
      gutter: 1em,
      ..authors.map(author => align(center, strong(author))),
    ),
  )

  // Main body.
  set par(justify: true)

  body
}
```

- Document Code:

```
#import "template.typ": *

// Take a look at the file `template.typ` in the file panel
// to customize this template and discover how it works.
#show: project.with(
  title: "Template",
  authors: (
    "Author",
  ),
  date: "January 6, 2024",
)

#h(.25cm) #set text(lang: "ru"); Как лучше всего получить то, что ты хочешь? - спросила она. Он посмотрел в землю, зная, что ей не понравится его ответ. Он колебался, зная, что правда только повредит. Как он собирался сказать ей это? лучший способ получить то, что он хотел, это оставить ее. Завтра я возвращаюсь в Колорадо после того, как на выходных провел там фестиваль в Санта-Барбаре. Там я буду строить планы на октябрь и постараюсь договориться, чтобы, если возможно, вернуться сюда на день рождения. Я сообщу вам, как только узнаю график приема врача и планы полетов. Стул стоял в углу, где простоял более 25 лет. Единственная разница заключалась в том, что в нем действительно кто-то сидел. Сколько времени прошло с тех пор, как кто-то это делал? По его мнению, десять лет или больше. И все же нельзя было отрицать присутствие в кресле сейчас.
```

Comment: But why *should* one expect LuaLaTeX and Typst to hyphenate in the exact same way anyway? They're two different typesetting systems, so presumably they have different algorithms for hyphenation/word-breaking.

Comment: @Felix  LaTeX, using microtype does such a good job here, that is why you do not see any hyphenation. Remove and try you will see one end of line hyphen.

Comment: Please, post an image of what you get with Typst (I don't have it installed, so I can’t compare), but very likely @yannisl is right.

Comment: As the other comments suggest, rather than comparing the typeset result perhaps you need to look at the calculations to see the potential hyphenation points? That's certainly doable in TeX and I can't believe Typst doesn't offer similar insight.

Comment: So you're complaining that TeX is performing better than Typst?

Comment: Typst is using the same hyphenation patterns (for most languages) as TeX, but a slightly different paragraph layout algorithm. Given that you configured both correctly, TeX likely did not choose to hyphenate because it layouted the paragraph differently, as the other commenters pointed out.

Comment: @Martin The reason was explained in my comment. I tried it wth typst as well and I can confirm, the pkg `microtype` improved TeX's layout. TeX also had an improved paragraph  without microtype as well. Typst is a good program, but hyphenation is not one of its advantages.  I will post images in an answer tomorrow and then vote to close if the OP does not.

Comment: unrelated but why do you start your examples with `% {` ?

Comment: According to Typst Discord server, there are still bugs in the way Typst hyphenates which can lead to excessive hyphenation. So some of the differences might not be related to microtype but just bugs or unoptimized hyphenation algorithm. There are many things which can cause differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX tries to avoid hyphenation and with long lines and rather short words it often succeeds. If you want a fast text how hyphenation works, set a small textwidth:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % loads fontspec
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[Ligatures=TeX]
\usepackage[main=english,spanish,russian]{babel} 

\textwidth=5pt
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
Как лучше всего получить то, что ты хочешь? - спросила она. Он посмотрел в землю, зная, что ей не понравится его ответ. Он колебался, зная, что правда только повредит. Как он собирался сказать ей это? лучший способ получить то, что он хотел, это оставить ее. Завтра я возвращаюсь в Колорадо после того, как на выходных провел там фестиваль в Санта-Барбаре. Там я буду строить планы на октябрь и постараюсь договориться, чтобы, если возможно, вернуться сюда на день рождения. Я сообщу вам, как только узнаю график приема врача и планы полетов. Стул стоял в углу, где простоял более 25 лет. Единственная разница заключалась в том, что в нем действительно кто-то сидел. Сколько времени прошло с тех пор, как кто-то это делал? По его мнению, десять лет или больше. И все же нельзя было отрицать присутствие в кресле сейчас.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on my comments and add some images. I did three tests:

1. **Using Typst**
   [image]
2. **Using LuaLaTeX with `microtype`**
   [image]
3. **Using LuaLaTeX without microtype.**
   [image]

As expected the best results were those using `microtype`. Of course a better test would have been using a narrow column, but I didn't know enough on the typst side to check it. Also using some difficult to hyphenate paragraphs, such as from the Frog King, would have been better, as well as to log all the parameters affecting hyphenation.

As an aside, here are also some comments on my experience with `typst`.

1. I installed it on Windows from the github repository without any problems (on Windows) and it took less than 2 minutes to have everything running (10/10).
2. I use sublime as an editor and although I had no package for highlighting typst code, it does produce clean and readable code (8/10).
3. Typst compiles extremely fast (10/10).
4. I also visited the discord server and was a very poor experience. I just don't really like visiting discord in general and getting hit with pop-ups to buy nitros. The community so far seems enthusiastic and supporting.  There are a lot of requests for features, that are taken for granted in LaTeX. (6/10)
5. I also Looked at some of the packages and IMHO Typst soon will have the same problem like Javascript, with an ecosystem that leads to indecisiveness, confusion and duplication. (5/10)
6. Overall it took less than 15 minutes for me to be able to use typst and read a little bit of the documentation. I did not watch the video, as I prefer to read than watch videos, is much quicker. I would have preferred a pdf in the like of LaTeX doc/docstrip documents. They bring a uniformity IMHO which is better than online manuals. (8/10)
7. IMHO it will be dead easy for both LaTeX as well as Typst to develop packages to translate to and from each other, either by the communities or `pandoc`.
8. Both Typst and LaTex so far are a better alternative to Word.

In a general environment of erosion of educational standards  exacerbated by a political leadership that indulges in empty rhetoric, is nice to see developments aiming at systems that can equip students and others to write better documents, rather than tweets.

Comment: Why do you say that LuaLaTeX with microtype is better than Typst when it came to the comparison.? Typst is shorter in size with its text. How did LuaLaTeX with microtype win? Also, your Lualatex photos look to have a different font to me

Comment: @FelixMaldonado  Well with `microtype` the text is justified properly without any hyphens! As for the font is the same. Can you let me know how to modify the typst code to reduce the paragraph width to say 0.2\textwidth?, That is how you need to check hyphenation, see Ultrike's post above.

Comment: @yannisl, you can easily change the page width in Typst by adding a `width` parameter in the `set page(...)` rule. For example: `width: 100pt`.

Comment: @Paapaa  Thanks. How do I change for only one paragraph? Similar to a parbox?

Comment: @yannisl One option would be to use the `block()` method. Ie: `#block(width: 100pt, [Как лучше всего получить то, что ты хочешь?])`. That seems to do the trick.

Comment: @FelixMaldonado The text lengths are nearly identical, and LuaLaTeX with microtype didn't need to use any hyphens to do it. Furthermore, I ran both on my machine, and for me *LuaLaTeX with microtype* was noticeably shorter than Typst. This just goes to show that you shouldn't exclusively use text length as a proxy for typographic quality anyway.

Comment: @Paapaa Thanks it works well with similar results, less hyphens with `microtype`. I always use it in my docs. As it slows down compilation I uncomment it after I am happy with my editing.